# Insert EndNote citation in Mac OS

Tags: mac-os-x, citation-management

I'm trying to insert [citations in a notebook](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/CitationManagement.html). I found [a thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Dec/msg00569.html) that goes back to 2010 saying that the Endnote plugin for Mathematica is not supported on Mac OS. Does anyone know whether this is still the case?

Comment: yes that is the case

Comment: thanks Mike. I'm trying it on windows but it seems if I cite a paper multiple times, mathematica gives it different numbers. Does anyone know if there is any way around it?

Comment: Sorry. I am a Mac user and although I tried prototypes of this it was 3 years ago and can't remember much about it.

Comment: Just for future reference, I'm trying this on Mathematica 10 and Endnote x7 and still receiving the same problem.